# HTML/CSS - place the image at the left of the text, but both at the center of the page

Tags: html, css

The image (header logo) must take such place as several lines of the text, buttons and other content. All the header must be at the center of the web-page. The width of the header must be "elastic".

Here is the approximate image of what I need:
[image: Site scheme]
EDIT: this is all the code I have:

```
<HTML><HEAD>
    <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</HEAD><BODY>
<HEADER><CENTER>
<IMG src="/files/????????.png" height=128 alt="logo" class="left">
This is some content of the header like text, links, buttons etc.
</CENTER></HEADER>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: put both in an enclosing container and center that element.

Comment: What means "enclosing container"?

Comment: just an extra div around it

Comment: Who is voting me down? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put both the image and the text in an enclosing container and then center that element.

```css
html, body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightpink;
  height: 200px;
}

.content p {
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  <img src="https://cataas.com/cat" class="image">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that container is placed vertically also in the center, not in the header. How to fix this?

Comment: And I have written that the width of the header must be elastic, not 50%. EDIT: there must be several lines of DIFFERENT content of different width, not one paragraph. And the width of the entire header must fit to the image plus the widest of lines.

Comment: elastic is not a css term I know of and you can just put this in a header element.

Comment: I put this into the <HEADER></HEADER> tags but this doesn't work, Elastic means that the width must automatically increase and reduce depending on the image plus the widest line.

Comment: How would you know how big it is supposed to be, since text has multiple points it can break up from. The width of the paragraph text is completely arbitrary.

Comment: I have written above, but still one time: that will be not the simple text, but multiple lines of the different content.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create this you need to use bootstrap and use this code for implementation.

It's a very blank example but enough for start to figure it out, how it's works. The script line is not necessary for your solution anyway. So if you want, you just delete this line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <IMG src="https://cataas.com/cat" height=128 alt="logo" class="left">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
           <p> This is some content of the header like text, links, buttons etc. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inserting external scripts into the web-page is very dangerous...

Comment: I think the bootsrap isn't dangerous. You can check it yourself at [link](https://getbootstrap.com/) It's built for easy, fast and responsive site creation.

Comment: Why would bootstrap be dangerous?

Comment: I don't know about exclusively the bootstrap, but I know that in general case the unknown scripts can contain viruses and trojans.

Comment: You can self-host bootstrap too if you really want to.

Comment: The bootsrap is well known script but the script line is not necessary for your solution anyway. So if you want, you just delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved so:

```css
.container
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
.content
{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    display: flex;
    background: lightpink;
    height: 128px;
}
.content p
{
    margin: 0;
}
.logo
{
    height: 128px;
}
```

```html
<HTML><HEAD>
    <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <LINK rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
</HEAD><BODY>
<HEADER><CENTER>
<DIV class="container">
    <DIV class="content">
        <IMG src="https://cataas.com/cat" class="logo">
        <DIV>
            <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</P>
            <P>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim</P>
            <P>ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco</P>
            <P>laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</P>
            <P>eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,</P>
            <P>sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</P>
        </DIV>
    </DIV>
</DIV>
</CENTER></HEADER>
</BODY></HTML>
```